# Cannot read property of 'undefined' Reactive Forms Angular 5, dropdown populated with remote data

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying Angular Reactive forms an I am trying to populate a dropdown with data from my server, after fetching the data, my dropdowns display all of the options but with blank text, What is the cause of this?

My small version of my html form

```
<form [formGroup]="new_element">
      <div>
           <input formControlName="title" />
      </div>
      <div>
         <select formControlName="question">
              <option *ngFor="let op of questions" [value]="op.questionId" >{{op.title}}</option>
         </select>
      </div>
</form>
```

my resumed version of the components class

```
questions: array<Question> = []
new_element: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
            private new_elService: NewElementService,
            private question_service: QuestionService) {
     // get questions from server for select calling question_service.getAll() method which is an observable
     this.createForm()
}

createForm() {
     this.new_element = this.fb.group({
          title: ['', Validator.required],
          question: ['', Validator.required]
     })
}
```

But then I get the error which is the title of my question, what should I do?

Comment: Can you update the question with json of the questions that you are trying to bind